How to call GitHub workflow command http-client
I need to invoke an API call from my GitHub workflow. The doc says "The actions/toolkit includes a number of functions that can be executed as workflow commands. Use the :: syntax to run the workflow commands within your YAML file". From actions/toolkit I found http-client. But I cannot find any example about how to call http-client as a workflow command.
If that http-client is not usable, how to invoke a http call from a workflow? Note, I am using an Enterprise Github instance, so action marketplace is not accessible.

why not use curl?
